# Symfony 6 : Get form errors when submit is in AJAX

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

### Context

In Symfony 6, I have an Entity 'Product' with multiple constraints.
I created a Form of this entity in a BootstrapModal for add new products

### Files

Twig :

```
{% block body %}

<!-- Product list -->
<table id="table"></table>

<!-- Add button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Add new product
</button>

<!-- Modal Form -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3> New product :</h3>
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.description) }}

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            var formData = $(this).serialize()

            $.ajax({
                url: '/product',
                data: formData,
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (result){
                    $('#modalContact').modal('hide')
                    $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh')
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Controller :

```
#[Route('/product', name: 'app_new_product', methods: ['POST', 'GET'])]
public function newProduct(Request $request, ProductRepository $productRepository)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $productForm = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
    $productForm->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($productForm->isSubmitted() && $productForm->isValid()) {
        $productRepository->save($product, true);
    }

    return $this->render('product.html.twig', [
        'form' => $productForm->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

### Question

I want to submit form and display errors form directely in the modal without refresh page.

Comment: In your use case and without that much refactoring, you could in your controller check if the request is from ajax ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()), and the form is invalid (!$productForm->isValid), then return the form errors to the view as json ($this->render JsonResponse($form->getErrors()). Then implement an $.ajax error callback function that inject error to the view.

Comment: If you are using ajax to submit your form then i would suggest not to use Form component instead use JavaScript library. In symfony then you can use MapRequestPayload attribute to your custom Request DTO for validation. 
See more on Document
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#mapping-request-payload